# Question about a mixed metaphor and the argument from causation

Tags: thomism

During this morning's *This Man is You* video, Dr. Peter Kreeft use an analogy of a freight car to explain St. Thomas's argument from causation (one of the famous five proofs).  He said that when you come to a train tracks and see a freight car moving, you know that the one in front of it is pulling it and the one in front of that is pulling it, etc.  until you come to the engine which is pulling all of them; and this is like God creating the universe.

Now, since this is a men's group, we naturally got to talking about trains and one of the fellows mentioned that it's common to have engines in the middle out west and also common to have them at the rear.

And I got to thinking, is God the prime mover puller or pusher?  Does that make a difference?

And, just to frame this as a question that I think is on topic and not purely philosophical does the Thomistic principle of God as the First Cause also work if you think of God as the Final Cause - does it make any difference; could God also be *all* the causes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distinction has little ultimate significance, but we can make arguments for both (in proper Thomistic fashion).

The difference between pushing and pulling is direction. Both describe an active power causing a change of position on some body. Pull describes a motion towards the agent whereas push causes a motion away from the agent.

How does this apply to God?

God is not a body and so doesn't have position so we cannot literally say push or pull because nothing is moved physically closer or farther from Him. However, analogically we can say creation is like a "push" because it starts from God as a first cause and goes out.

In a second way, God created for Himself so all creation points back towards Him and He desires us to come to him. Thus, he also analogically "pulls."

This is incidentally the Platonic principle of *exitus et reditus* (going out and return), which is how the Summa is structured. The Summa starts with God and creation (the 5 proofs, God's attributes, Trinity, angels, man, souls, etc) then the Prima Secundae and Secunda Secundae cover ethics (the last end, happiness, vices and virtues) and the Tertia Pars covers Christ and sacraments (Incarnation, Passion, Grace, Salvation).

God is the first cause in that everything else is caused by Him. God is also the final cause in that everything else that exists exists for Him.